# Using Font Awesome in Laravel's Forms Submit button?

Tags: css, laravel, font-awesome, laravel-form

I have the following form that works as a 'Delete' button.

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['notes.delete', $note->user->id]]) }}
{{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Is there a way to replace the "Delete" button text with a Font Awesome icon? I tried changing it to:

```
{{ Form::submit('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
```

However, it does not display the icon, but just the raw version of HTML code - `<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>`. Is there a way to use Font Awesome with Laravel forms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use Form::submit, the contents are always escaped. You can use Form::button instead, which does not escape the content.

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm', 'type' => 'submit']) }}
```

Important to notice here is  `'type' => 'submit'` added after `class`.